# Don't rewrite particular subfolder

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using the following `.htaccess` to rewrite all URLs to my index.php file if they're not actual files or folders:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

// This bit redirect www.mydomain.com to mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

// This bit redirects all requests to index.php if a file or directory
// bearing that name doesn't exist
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

I'm now adding an `admin` section to my website and I would like to **not** rewrite this particular URL:

```
mydomain.com/admin
```

I would like that case to be treated as it would be by default (in this case defaulting to `mydomain.com/admin/index.php` )

I've attempted to figure this out by myself but `regex` is still alien to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

// This bit redirect www.mydomain.com to mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

// This bit redirects all requests to index.php if a file or directory
// bearing that name doesn't exist OR it doesn't start with /admin/
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^admin/ ./index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: This worked on my localhost server but for some reason doesn't work on my webhost! Any idea why on a live host it still redirects `mydomain.com/admin`?

Comment: There is nothing special in these rules about localhost. Just make sure mod_rewrite and .htaccess is enabled on live server and place these rules in DocumentRoot (a level above admin)